# Problem with non-descriptive question titles

Tags: discussion, title, asking-questions

Is it OK having around 30 [questions titled "regular expression problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22regular+expression+problem%22+intitle%3A1)?

What should be done when a new question with a title like this ("feature problem" or "feature problem in Language" or "adjective feature problem in Language")  appears?  Is it a symptom of questions that are too localized?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's a problem.

Editors should change them as much as they are able to.

People don't like to make expansive changes, but these are prime examples where they're needed.

Answer (score 5):

These titles should be edited to make them more descriptive of the problem.

If the main body of the question doesn't have enough information for you to determine what the user wants, you can leave a comment asking for more info, or just downvote.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote without a comment in this case.  No sense in handing out punishment without explaining how to fix it/avoid similar future punishment.

Comment: @Pop - agreed. Downvoting/commenting is the user's prerogative, though.

Comment: yep 15char

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly not ideal, but it's not the end of the world, either.  There's not much we can do besides let the community sort it out through the usual editing process.  Most of those questions are from before 2010, when there were fewer users with edit power.  This answer is partially born of necessity, as I'm not aware of any vagueness detection algorithm that won't turn out loads of false positives and false negatives.

Probably the best we could do is a small warning like the "your question appears to be subjective" banner, but how many of those banners are we okay with having?  Or, if modifying it rather than adding a new banner, how many purposes are we okay with having it serve?  One seems like a good cap to me.

Yes, those questions area bit localized, but — I assume, since I haven't read each one — they do discuss different issues with regexes, and there's still some value to having them around.  They certainly will be hard to find by people with similar problems, though.

Answer (score 2):

Heh. I was just coming here to ask the same thing, after renaming the latest of those. (Though having to tidy up isn't exactly enjoyable).

We've already got the "subjective" check on question title, so in theory we can use the same logic to look for `<technology> problem` and similar and show another warning.

Although not sure how much the warning would help - if the check could be made accurate enough I think I'd be in favour of forcing a title re-write.